# Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential(Deploy)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, bitbucket

I would like to deploy BitBucket to Google App Engine, I have done the all configuartion using [bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-google-cloud/](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-to-google-cloud/) this link. I am getting below error, You can see my log as follows on bitbucket deployment :-

```
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/evadev0010/services/default/versions?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Mon, 29 Jun 2020 11:56:01 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '400', 'content-length': '145', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
>
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime.
+ status=1
+ set -e
+
```

Any help to resolve this issue

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Hello, as far as I know in flex you can do it this from the yaml file.In App Engine standard you have to edit the appengine-web.xml. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) official documentation.

Comment: Please, let us know if you are still facing your issue, otherwise please post the answer.